gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
I am trying to sign a git commit in Termux, but I receive an error:
$ git commit -S -m "my commit message"
error: gpg failed to sign the data:
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN 2
[GNUPG:] BEGIN_SIGNING H10
[GNUPG:] PINENTRY_LAUNCHED 16900 curses 1.3.0 - xterm-256color - - 10196/10196 0
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[GNUPG:] FAILURE sign NNNNNNNN
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
fatal: failed to write commit object


The term xterm may indicate that gpg is trying to open a new terminal window which fails because you only have that one terminal. That page seems to discuss this topic: https://ertt.ca/blog/2022/01-10-git-gpg-ssh/
